# Adding a hot tub which needs a 220 60 amp circuit

Tags: hot-tub

I reviewed some other questions - none of them seemed to be similar enough to consider.

I am planning on using an electrician for this upgrade and want to be able to explain to him on the phone our needs. We're out in the country and I'd like to have a much info for him before he visits.

We are getting a new hot tub which needs 220V/60 amp service. As part of our recent remodel, we already ran heavy gauge wire which we were told was big enough for the circuit - I don't think this part will be an issue and I'm sure the electrician will verify - I think it's at least 6 gauge my even be 4.

Our current master breaker box has a 220 outlet with dual pole 30 amp breakers which was used for a shop air compressor previously. The plan is to connect the hot tub to this breaker (with the new wire of course).

We need to replace this breaker with one that fits the needs of the hot tub. From a replacement perspective, is this as "simple" as replacing the current dual pole 30 amp with a 60 amp breaker?

I know when the electrician comes, he'll make sure it's done properly, but I'm trying to get an idea of the complexity.

Comment: What make and model is your breaker box?

Comment: Siemens G4040B1200    225 service

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the wires are appropriate for 60 amps (6awg copper is rated for 55 amps at 60c and I believe you are allowed to “round up” to the next higher breaker size, 60 amps) then yes, you can simply replace the old dual 30 amp breaker with a dual 60. (Cap off or remove the old wires running to the 30.)

Note that a hot tub requires GFCI protection. This can be done by using a 60 amp GFCI breaker in your panel or by using a GFCI cutoff switch near the hot tub.

Comment: That all needs to be done Gfci breaker.  Get all the information of what type of panel it is. So he can bring the proper breaker.

Comment: Thank you. I will take a pic of the placard to send him.